# How to use per directory url structure for Rails internationalization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, routes

I am in the process of internationalizing a Rails app (3.1) for the first time, and I would like to use the following url structure:

```
www.domain.com/rest-of-url for english (default language)
www.domain.com/es/rest-of-url for spanish
```

I cant seem to find any info on how to do this. I think I have to work on my ApplicationController and routes file, but I get lost easily with the latter, so please explain your solution.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

there are some decent examples of how to integrate i18n into your rails-application in the guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params

in short this would be

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
def default_url_options(options={})
  logger.debug "default_url_options is passed options: #{options.inspect}\n"
  { :locale => I18n.locale }
end
```

-

```
# config/routes.rb
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|es/ do
  resources :books
end
```

Comment: Thank you, but I already read that guide and that didnt work for me for some reason. Also, wouldnt that make my url structure for both languages use subdirectories?

Comment: So would I have to put all of my routes inside that scope? I dont really get what that code does...